# Python view vs copy error wants me to use .loc in script only

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a long script which has a dataframe `df`. as the script runs, building up and modifying `df` column by column I get this error over and over again in the command line:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in
>   the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

But then it will print out the line that is causing the warning and it wont look like a problem. Lines such as the following will trigger it (each line triggered it separately):

```
df['ZIP_DENS'] = df['ZIP_DENS'].astype(str)
df['AVG_WAGE'] = df['AVG_WAGE'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x if x != 'nan' else 'unknown')
df['TERM_BIN'] = df['TERMS'].map(terms_dict)
df['LOSS_ONE'] = 'T_'+ df['TERM'].astype(str) +'_C_'+ df['COMP'].astype(str) + df['SIZE']
# this one's inside a loop:
df[i + '_BIN'] = df[i + '_BIN'].apply(lambda x:x if x != 'nan' else 'unknown')
```

There are some examples of the mutations I'm making on the dataframe. Now, this warning just started showing up but I can't recreate this problem in the interpreter. When I open a terminal I try things like this and it gives me no warnings:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([list('ab'),list('ef')],columns=['first','second'])
df['third'] = df[['first','second']].astype('str')
```

Is there something I'm missing, something I don't understand about the nature of DataFrames that this warning is trying to tell me? Do you think perhaps I did something to this dataframe at the beginning of the script and then all subsequent mutations on the object are mutations on a view or a copy of it or something weird like that is going on?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Remember it's just a warning. This does not mean there are any miscalculations.

Comment: My guess is you have a statement like `df = somedf[list_of_rows, list_of_columns]` somewhere upstream in your code. So now df points to a slice, i.e. location in memory of somedf, rather than to a view, i.e. the values in the slice which you get using .loc.
So every time you set anything in this new df now, you will get the warning message. I would advise to just use loc instead - it's similar syntax for the most part. Alternatively you can write `df = somedf[list_of_rows, list_of_columns].copy()` instead when you are making that initial assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the likely issue is that somewhere upstream in your code, you assigned a slice of some other `pd.DataFrame` to `df`. 
This is a common cause of confusion and is also explained under [why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) in the link that the `Warning` mentions.

A minimal example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(7), 'b':list('abcccdb')})
df = data[data.a % 2 == 0]  #making a subselection of the DataFrame  
df['b'] = 'b'
```

> /home/user/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Notice that this section:

```
df = data[data.a % 2 == 0]  #making a subselection of the DataFrame  
df['b'] = 'b'
```

could just as well be rewritten this way:

```
data[data.a % 2 == 0]['b'] = 'b'  #obvious chained indexing  
df = data[data.a % 2 == 0]
```

The correct way of writing this bit is the following way:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(7), 'b':list('abcccdb')})
df = data.loc[data.a % 2 == 0].copy()  #making a copy of the subselection   
df.loc[:,'b'] = 'b'
```

Comment: you're right I traced it back to this line `df[new_col_name] = temp[new_col_name]` so then I replaced that with a merge and its working fine. `temp = temp.drop([metric, column], axis=1); df = df.merge(temp, indicator=False, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: Glad I could help - it's not quite intuitive, I know!